# How to change the button`s name on Mouse Hover

Tags: vb.net

Q- When a 'Mouse Hover action' is used for a button (N.B: the button has a name-Text it shows under properties- we wish to change that name when the mouse hovers over it as well as change the font color of the textfield (textbox) from blue to red). Please can you`ll help me to change the name of the button component and color issue.

**Code Attempt: (Visual Basic 10 Express)**

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover 

    Button1.Name("About to go Red") 

  End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  What platform are you using?  WinForms, WPF, etc.  Post your code attempt.

Comment: I`m stuck on how to change the button`s original name by using the Mouse Hover action. I`m using Microsoft Visual Basic 10 Express . Thank You for answering me .

Comment: Explain the stuck part.  Do you know how to subscribe to the MouseHover event?  Do you want to change the name of the button, or the text displayed on the button.

Comment: Okay. Hmmm it`s a very trail and error code. I just started learning coding in VB but know how to design in it . Posting just now

Comment: I know how to choose the event explained in the practical but changing the name I set under properties of the button by coding under the Event 'MouseHover' I`m getting confused...

Comment: **Public Class Form1**

 _Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover_
        Button1.Name("About to go Red")

    **End Sub**
**End Class**

Answer (score 1):

When you click buttton in Properties, there is an icon looking like a lightning bolt which is for events.
Click that icon, and search for the event MouseHover

As I don't know if you actually mean the design name, or the text it shows.

For the text:

```
    Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover


    Button1.text = R.Next(0, 10)
End Sub
```

For the name:

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Button1.Name = R.Next(0, 10)
End Sub
```

Ofcourse you can edit R.Next to any thing you want.

Comment: Thank you. Can I please ask about 'R' what can I put in it`s place ?

Comment: You can but any type of string like this: "I hovered over this, and it changed to this text, neat!"

Comment: That`s neat, then the Next(0-10) part specifies the range of characters that is allowed in String 'R' ?

Comment: I believe they're using [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Sherenica : No, programming doesn't work that way. `R` in this context is an instance of the [**`Random` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx). Calling the [**`Random.Next()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) like `Next(0, 10)` will just pick a random number between 0-9. Setting it to the button's text will just cause it to display that number.